# Possible to upload and replace a ghostable file in the style library?

Tags: ghosting, style-library

As title says, I have a file which is the same name/type of an already existing file in the style library (image, for discussion sake). I get an error when attempting to upload a file via the UI (file already exists error).

Is it possible to force an overwrite of this file?

Answer (score 1):

http://kmukesh.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/upload-file-in-sharepoint-style-library-using-powershell/

^ The above article answers my question. The boolean passed into Files.Add() dictates whether the file can be overwritten or not.